# Issues in declaring variables

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

am trying to make a Petition form for a local company (A required project for graduation).

This is part of my page where I am facing troubles:

```
<FORM METHOD="POST"  ACTION="InsertPetition.asp?EmpID=<%=Request.QueryString("EmpID")%>&BRANCH=<%=Session("BRANCH")%>" name=frmNewClaim>
<table>
<tr>                        
<td>From Date</td>
<td><SELECT name=cboFromDateDay>
<%For i = 1 To 31%>
<%if i=day(date()) then%>
<OPTION VALUE="<%=i%>" Selected="True"><%=i%></OPTION>
<%else%>
<OPTION VALUE="<%=i%>"><%=i%></OPTION>
<%end if%>
<%Next%>
</SELECT>

<SELECT name=cboFromDateMonth>
<%For i = 1 To 12%>
<%if i=month(date()) then%>
<OPTION VALUE="<%=i%>" Selected="True"><%=MonthName(i)%></OPTION>
<%else%>
<OPTION VALUE="<%=i%>"><%=MonthName(i)%></OPTION>
<%end if%>
<%Next%>
</SELECT>

<SELECT name=cboFromDateYear>
<%For i = Year(Date())-1 To Year(Date()) + 10%>
<%if i=year(date()) then%>
<OPTION VALUE="<%=i%>" Selected="True"><%=i%></OPTION>
<%else%>
<OPTION VALUE="<%=i%>"><%=i%></OPTION>
<%end if%>
<%Next%>
</SELECT>
</td>   
<td><INPUT type="button" value="Submit" name=cmdSubmit></td>


</tr>
</table>
```

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT">

Sub cmdClose_OnClick()
    window.close
End Sub

Sub cmdSubmit_OnClick()
    Dim fromdate2
    Dim todate2
    fromdate2="Trim(frmNewClaim.cboFromDateDay.Value) & "/" & Trim(frmNewClaim.cboFromDateMonth.Value) & "/" & Trim(frmNewClaim.cboFromDateYear.Value)" 
    todate2="Trim(frmNewClaim.cboToDateDay.Value) & "/" & Trim(frmNewClaim.cboToDateMonth.Value) & "/" & Trim(frmNewClaim.cboToDateYear.Value)"

    Select case frmNewClaim.txtPTNGroup.Value
        'If type is Birth
        case 30
               if DateDiff("d",fromdate2,todate2) > 45 then
               msgbox "Days value exceeded the limit of days allowed!",16,"Data Entry Error"
               frmNewClaim.txtPTNGroup.focus
               Exit Sub
               end if
case else 
        End Select
frmNewClaim.submit

    End Sub
```

In this form, the user is required to insert day, month, year in the `from date` and the `to date` table row after selecting the type of the petition for example : Birth
In the script, i declared variables `fromdate2` and `todate2`which are supposed to contain the date for example like this: "03/12/2015"
and in the select case `case 30`, the `datediff` function which will give me the amount of days between the `fromdate2` `todate2` and if it is less then 45 then a message box would appear (yes, i know it only works on IE) say the days exceeded the limit

**The problem is** when i test it and click `submit` nothing happens 
Am pretty sure the error is in the `fromdate2` `todate2` variables
Help me and thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm confused as to how you are trying to collect your form data.  Unless I'm missing something you appear to be mixing server side and client side code.

Classic ASP is a server side technology, VBScript is the language it usually uses, (you can specify JavaScript if you prefer.)

Your subroutines are contained within `<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT">`.  This means that it will be run client side - and as you are aware it will only work on IE

I think what you need to do is to first move your code to the server side.  You can do this either by putting it inside `<%  %>` delimiters, or by using `<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" runat="server">`

Instead of onclick events use the request object to populate variables retrieved from your form fields, eg `cboFromDateDay = Request.Form("cboFromDateDay")`

Finally your vbs script seems designed to generate popup alerts.  This wouldn't work with server side code.  You could use `Response.Write` to have error messages appear within the text of your page.

If you desperately want popup alerts then you could have them triggered when the page loads, and put the code which triggers them within an asp conditional statement so that it only appears in the server output if certain conditions are met.  I would suggest though that this is more trouble than it's worth